# c# Cannot parse JSON response from GET memberof request to the Azure Graph API

Tags: c#, json, azure-ad-graph-api

I am unable to parse some JSON into my classes.

I get the following JSON in my response from a GET memberof request to the Azure Graph API:

```
{
   "odatametadata":"https://graph.windows.net/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#directoryObjects",
   "value":[
      {
         "odatatype":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.DirectoryRole",
         "objectType":"Role",
         "objectId":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "deletionTimestamp":null,
         "description":"Company Administrator role has full access to perform any operation in the company scope.",
         "displayName":"Company Administrator",
         "isSystem":true,
         "roleDisabled":false,
         "roleTemplateId":"cccccccc-cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc"
      },
      {
         "odatatype":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group",
         "objectType":"Group",
         "objectId":"vvvvvvvv-vvvv-vvvv-vvvv-vvvvvvvvvvvv",
         "deletionTimestamp":null,
         "description":"Test Group",
         "dirSyncEnabled":null,
         "displayName":"Testing",
         "lastDirSyncTime":null,
         "mail":null,
         "mailNickname":"ssssssss-ssss-ssss-ssss-ssssssssssss",
         "mailEnabled":false,
         "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,
         "provisioningErrors":[

         ],
         "proxyAddresses":[

         ],
         "securityEnabled":true
      },
      {
         "odatatype":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group",
         "objectType":"Group",
         "objectId":"dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-ddddddddddd",
         "deletionTimestamp":null,
         "description":"Application Admin Users",
         "dirSyncEnabled":null,
         "displayName":"ApplicationAdmin",
         "lastDirSyncTime":null,
         "mail":null,
         "mailNickname":"qqqqqqqq-qqqq-qqqq-qqqq-qqqqqqqqqqq",
         "mailEnabled":false,
         "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,
         "provisioningErrors":[

         ],
         "proxyAddresses":[

         ],
         "securityEnabled":true
      }
   ]
}
```

These are my classes:

```
    public class RootValue
{
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }
    public List<value> valuelist;
    //public List<Dictionary<string, value>> vals;
}


public class value
{
    //[JsonProperty( "first_name" )]
    public string odatatype { get; set; }
    public string objectType { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public object deletionTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool isSystem { get; set; }
    public bool roleDisabled { get; set; }
    public string roleTemplateId { get; set; }
    public object dirSyncEnabled { get; set; }
    public object lastDirSyncTime { get; set; }
    public object mail { get; set; }
    public string mailNickname { get; set; }
    public bool? mailEnabled { get; set; }
    public object onPremisesSecurityIdentifier { get; set; }
    public List<object> provisioningErrors { get; set; }
    public List<object> proxyAddresses { get; set; }
    public bool? securityEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Using Newtonsoft:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootValue>( myjsonstring);
```

The odatametadata value is populated, but the valuelist is null.

Comment: Because the JSON propertyname is "value", not "valuelist".

Comment: If the first data block exactly what you got from Fiddler (not F12), then I'd suggest start from one element for "value" at a time until it longer be able to populate.

Comment: No, your valueList is not null, it has 3 items. I've tested your code, there is no issue with your code, it works fine for me.